# Share an Intellij Python Project Between Windows and OSX

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I have an Intellij 15 Python project created using the Python plugin. I'm on OSX and have the Project Python SDK set to `/usr/bin/python`. I've got another developer on my team that is on Windows and his SDK is at `C:\Python27\Python.exe`

Is there any way I can share this project via source control without us both stepping over each other toes each time I update and need to change the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You can always put your .idea folder into .gitignore (or equivalent for your VS) file and prevent sharing it between systems and developers.

If you don't have project-specific settings there - it's recommended way to do it.